# Notice: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'

Tags: php, sql, security

Okay, I'm really confused. I can't seem to see where I went wrong with this invalid parameter number thing. Could I get a hand with identifying where I'm going wrong?

**Get SQL Query and Set up Parameters**

```
public function do_retrieve_stored_message_data()
    {
        $m_sql_query_string = CourseWorkSqlQuery::get_message_data();
        $m_message_data = $this->c_arr_display_stored_message_data['sanitised-message-data'];
        $m_arr_sql_query_parameters = 
        array(':message_date' => $m_message_data,
                ':message_time' => $m_message_data,
                ':message_last_value' => $m_message_data);

        $m_result = $this->c_obj_database_handle->safe_query($m_sql_query_string, $m_arr_sql_query_parameters);
```

**SQL Query String**

```
public static function get_message_data()
    {
        $m_sql_query_string  =  "SELECT message_date, message_time, message_last_value ";
        $m_sql_query_string .=  "FROM cw_messages ";
        $m_sql_query_string .=  "WHERE message_date = :message_date ";
        $m_sql_query_string .=  "AND message_time = :message_time ";
        $m_sql_query_string .=  "AND message_last_value= :message_last_value ";
        $m_sql_query_string .=  "LIMIT 1";
        return $m_sql_query_string;
    }
```

**Database Handler**

```
public function safe_query($p_query_string, $p_arr_params)
    {
        $m_database_query_execute_error = true;
        $m_query_string = $p_query_string;
        $m_arr_query_parameters = $p_arr_params;

        try
        {
            $m_temp = array();
            $this->c_obj_database_handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $this->c_obj_stmt = $this->c_obj_database_handle->prepare($m_query_string);

            // bind the parameters
            if (sizeof($m_arr_query_parameters) > 0)
            {
                foreach ($m_arr_query_parameters as $m_param_key => $m_param_value)
                {
                    $m_temp[$m_param_key] = $m_param_value;
                    $this->c_obj_stmt->bindParam($m_param_key, $m_temp[$m_param_key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                }
            }

            // execute the query
            $m_execute_result = $this->c_obj_stmt->execute();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sidenote: You should put some spacing for your query. As it stands, your query is being read like this `SELECT message_date, message_time, message_last_valueFROM cw_messagesWHERE message_date = :message_dateAND message_time = :message_timeAND LIMIT1message_last_value= :message_last_value` all bunched up together.

Comment: You might have abstracted away all this program-specific gubbins to produce a PURE PHP TESTCASE.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The parameters are in the top code block called "$m_arr_sql_query_parameters"

Comment: @Raisus: Yes, I can see that. But I had to look quite hard for it. What prevented you from constructing a ten-line testcase in a single function with short, self-explanatory variable names? It doesn't have to look like your real code as long as it reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED:

Long story, short, I tried to assign all 3 parameters to 1 variable. So to change this, I swapped:

**OLD CODE**

```
..
..
$m_arr_sql_query_parameters = 
    array(':message_date' => $m_message_data,
            ':message_time' => $m_message_data,
            ':message_last_value' => $m_message_data);
..
..
```

**NEW CODE**

```
..
..
$m_arr_sql_query_parameters = 
    array(':message_date' => $m_message_date,
            ':message_time' => $m_message_time,
            ':message_last_value' => $m_message_last_value);
..
..
```

And this fixed my problem. Good to know you can't assign more than one paranter to a variable. Feel free to close this Query.

Comment: @php-dev "You can accept your own answer tomorrow" - As soon as it comes around, I will